# Is there a way to change the route variable separator in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, variables, zend-route, zend-controller-router

I'd like to change the way URLs that Zend Framework is generating from this:

```
$routeString = '/section/:sectionName';
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(routeString, array( etc, etc... );
```

...to this...

```
$routeString = '/section_:sectionName';
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(routeString, array( etc, etc... );
```

Note that in the second option the middle slash in `$routeString` is replaced by an underscore.

When I make this change, the router stops recognizing the route and variables. I find it quite strange that the framework would impose such thing so I'm sure I'm missing something in the docs.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could do it using [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex). As an example I'll provide setup for your route in the application.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.section.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex" 
resources.router.routes.section.route = "section_(\d+)"
resources.router.routes.section.defaults.module = yourmodule
resources.router.routes.section.defaults.controller = yourcontroller
resources.router.routes.section.defaults.action = youraction
resources.router.routes.section.map.1 = "sectionName"
resources.router.routes.section.reverse = "section/%d"
```

Hope this will help you or at least point you in the right direction.